# Recounting lines which are crossing rastercell multiple times using Spatial Join in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

[image: Starting point]

I am performing a Spatial Join in ArcGIS.

Is there any possibility where i can recount a line that crosses a square multiple times?

With the normal way of the Spatial Join i get a Joincount where the line is just count as one even if the line crosses muliple times.

Answer (score 1):

First use Intersect tool. Then use "Multipart To Singlepart" tool. Then use spatial join.

By doing so you will get the desired result!

Comment: I tried this already. The Problem with this way is that the lines get split in small parts where they cross each other. The result is that u get a value that is way to high. Thank you anyway.

Comment: But at last you will get the correct Joincount from spatial join. remember that all the intermediate data are temporary.

Comment: If u take the highlighted line in the picture for example. What you would get as a result using your method is a joincount of 8 for the cell right in the middle. What i want as a result is 4. The Result of the actual spatial join would be 3 like u can see

Comment: If you could convert your squares to lines, use them to split your green lines then run a spatial join that might work.  But I don't know if ArcGIS can do that; ET Geowizard's split line by feature may.  In ArcGIS if you do what Farid suggested but inserted an extra step after the Intersect, a dissolve based on the squares attributes, would that work?